# How many squares in a finite group?

Tags: finite-groups, symmetric-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and denote by $S[G]$ the number of squares in $G$.
The maximum, $S[G]=n$, is attained for a group of odd order $n$ since each
element has a square root in that case. At the other extreme, $S[G]= 1$
when $G$ is an elementary abelian $2$-group because every element squares
to the identity. Other examples include: $S[Sym(4)] = 12$ and $S[Sym(6)] = 270$
for symmetric groups, while both the dihedral and quaternion group of order $8$
have $S[G] = 2$.

Questions:

1. Can $S[G]$ be determined from the character table of $G$?
2. Are the values of $S[G]$ known for the matrix groups $GL(2,q)$ and $GL(3,q)$?
3. A table for $S[Sym(n)]$ is given in [sequence A003483 at OEIS](https://oeis.org/A003483).  For $n>3$, is it true that $S[Sym(n)]$ is divisible by all the primes less than or equal to $n$?

Thanks

Comment: It might be good to post these as separate questions; I think I could probably answer question 3 if I thought about it, but am less sure about the others - you'd be more likely to get an answer for each one individually if you separated them (and you could put links to the others in each one)

Comment: Crossposted to MO (at least 1 and 3): http://mathoverflow.net/questions/221157/number-of-squares-in-a-finite-group